# React router not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a simple react-router setup. Please see my code here -

https://github.com/rocky-jaiswal/lehrer-node/tree/master/frontend

It is the most basic setup for react-router, however in the browser I cannot get it working -

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import IndexContainer from './components/index-container';
import AboutContainer from './components/about-container';
import PagesContainer from './components/pages-container';

(function main() {
  ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={IndexContainer}>
        <Route path="about" component={AboutContainer} />
        <Route path="pages" component={PagesContainer} />
      </Route>
    </Router>),
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
})();
```

The trouble also is there is no error reported on the console. Even I change the URL the **IndexComponent** is always mounted. Also if I type http://localhost:3333/#/about it changes to http://localhost:3333/#/about?_k=bac2pt somehow and stays on the IndexComponent.

Could there be something wrong with my simple webpack config or versions of react / react-router?

Thanks,
Rocky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexContainer` is your parent component, try adding `{ this.props.children }` in your `render()` so `AboutContainer` and `PagesContainer` will show.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, thanks to you I also got it working with -
    `<Router>
      <Route path="/" component={IndexContainer} />
      <Route path="/about" component={AboutContainer} />
      <Route path="/pages" component={PagesContainer} />
    </Router>`